# Emulate simple logical rules with ML

Tags: machine-learning, beginner

I have the following question. I have created a sample dataset based on a some simple boolean rules. The data describes the shipping cost for a store.
The features are :

- order value (range between 1-1000),
- aboard (Boolean 0 or 1)
- urgent( 0 and 1)

Depending on the values the shipping cost are calculated. Because of the boolean rules my shipping cost can have only 12 discreet values.

Now I would like to use a ML algorithm to emulate the logic I used to generate the sample data. I would like to train an algorithm with my data so that I can predict the shipping costs for new data points.

What would be the best choice for an algorithm?

I tried to use a NN but the results are not that good.

THX

Michael

Comment: Check your NN implementation again, especially that you're using the right loss function and metrics for a 12-category target. I would think a NN wouldn't have issues learning this. You can compare it to a Decision Tree classifier too.

Comment: a few obvious questions regarding *'NN results are not that good.'* - how large is your dataset? What is the architecture of your NN? Did you frame it as a classification or regression problem?

Comment: but as I always stress, as a beginner, do **not** jump straight into advance stuffs e.g. NN, GBT, LSTM etc.. Spend some good time and build yourself a solid foundation on the fundamentals instead.

Comment: shall you have a little knowledge in the area, you can immediate tell that a vanilla decision tree is all you need.